# How to run Flutter on the Github Codespaces like as run it on my desktop?

Tags: flutter, github, codespaces

I'm trying to use Github Codespaces to run my Flutter app. But's seem like Codespaces didn't officially support Flutter yet. It can run Dart normally. But when I try to run my Flutter app, it seems tricky and efficient is not very well. Anyone have a solution or settings for .devcontainer?? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can create your own `.devcontainer` folder and add the image.
Here are 2 examples

https://github.com/DanTup/github-codespaces-flutter-web

And

https://medium.com/flutter-community/github-codespaces-code-on-the-go-with-flutter-a6b550b3342b